# Track social activity for any subdomain

Tags: tracking, social-media, multi-subdomains

We are working on a web application thats actually a network of subdomains. Each user own a subdomain for its own profile. We are looking for a way to track social activity, shares and likes for all network under one profile. We tried using addthis but they don't support a feature like this.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using any analytics programs? Google Analytics has social event tracking and it integrates with [AddThis](http://www.addthis.com/).

Here these for more info:

[Google Analytics Social Tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSocial)

[Google Analytics Addthis integration](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381260-google-analytics-integration#.UjDz0WRgaaE)

Comment: In order to work with AddThis correctly i ll need to create separate profile for each sudb-domain in AddThis. We have a network of more than 600 sub-domains already, we are looking for one-for-all solution.